# What is the simplest way to extend Castle windsor to support private constructors for every service

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

We want to be able to Resolve services using Castle for implementation with private constructors.

This is a fictive "use case" for that:

```
public class SingletonClass : ISingletonClass
{

   private SingletonClass() {...} // Class users cannot create an instance

   public ISingletonClass Instance 
   { 
      get 
      {
         // The intention here is to get an instance of this service
         // it has previously been configured as singleton in the container
         return Container.Resolve<ISingletonClass>();
      }
   } 
}
```

We want to have the option to use those private constructors for every service, not only for a few specific cases.  Hence, we're looking for a simple and generic solution for this.

We looked for a solution using a custom component activator but found that we have to overrides a not-so trivial part of the default component activator, e.g. CreateInstance method.

This is the code for this in the default component activator:

```
    protected virtual object CreateInstance(CreationContext context, object[] arguments, Type[] signature)
    {
        object instance = null;
        Exception exception;
        Type implementation = base.Model.Implementation;
        bool flag = base.Kernel.ProxyFactory.ShouldCreateProxy(base.Model);
        bool flag2 = true;
        if (!(flag || !base.Model.Implementation.IsAbstract))
        {
            throw new ComponentRegistrationException(string.Format("Type {0} is abstract.{2} As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of {1} service", base.Model.Implementation.FullName, base.Model.Service.FullName, Environment.NewLine));
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            flag2 = base.Kernel.ProxyFactory.RequiresTargetInstance(base.Kernel, base.Model);
        }
        if (flag2)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.useFastCreateInstance)
                {
                    instance = FastCreateInstance(implementation, arguments, signature);
                }
                else
                {
                    instance = ActivatorCreateInstance(implementation, arguments);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception1)
            {
                exception = exception1;
                throw new ComponentActivatorException("ComponentActivator: could not instantiate " + base.Model.Implementation.FullName, exception);
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            try
            {
                instance = base.Kernel.ProxyFactory.Create(base.Kernel, instance, base.Model, context, arguments);
            }
            catch (Exception exception2)
            {
                exception = exception2;
                throw new ComponentActivatorException("ComponentActivator: could not proxy " + base.Model.Implementation.FullName, exception);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

It would be much easier if we could only overrides "ActivatorCreateInstance" or "FastCreateInstance" but they're closed.

Are we on the wrong track?
Is there a much simpler way to do this in a generic manner?

Thank you very much
Phil

Comment: you are on the wrong track by trying to do it in the first place. Just don't.

Comment: I agree with Krzysztof, this is a bad idea. Please explain your underlying issue, we might be able to give you a better solution...

Comment: BTW you don't need to use reflector to see the source code, it's an open source project: http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.InversionOfControl/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/ComponentActivator/DefaultComponentActivator.cs#L91

Comment: I'd really like to know why it is a bad idea?
Doesn't it depend on the context where we use this or it's simply bad that a container has to use a private constructor?

One of the case where i want to use this, is the Singleton example.  I know this is not a valid IoC practice because singleton "clients" have to know about the concrete implementation, but in some case, it is convenient.  I just want to know how we could do it with castle.

Comment: Ok, but why do you even need a static singleton? Why private constructors? Please understand that we ask this because it would be *very rare* in our experience to have a valid reason to do this.

Comment: Private or Internal constructors could be useful to "control" the construction of an object (Factory, Container, ...) but still want to expose this class and not just the interface.
Yes, it may be rare where it is really justified.  But I'm sure there's some place it is and other where you have more benefits than pains using this.  Even if it is not the absolute best thing to do.

Comment: **The container** is there to construct your objects period. Creating limitations and then have the container hack and workaround them is just wrong. Work with the container, not against it. It is a conscious and deliberate decision in Windsor to not support non-public constructors. Don't try to shoot yourself in the foot because your design is flawed. Fix the design.

Comment: I would use the container <b>only</b> for object's construction... period.  The only thing I would like to do in this simple example, is to use a private, internal constructor instead of a public one.  You think it is undeniably a design flaw, I say it all depends on your context.  Still, thank you for your comments and your desire for good design in software development.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an open-source project, you can write your own component activator by copying and pasting the DefaultComponentActivator code, changing what you need and registering the activator. I've done it a few times with several other components of the Castle stack. When it's done, send in a patch.